# High render usage with animations on mouse move

Tags: css, css-animations, chromium

I found some interesting behavior when testing the performance of some CSS animations. For example, I can animate these 1,000 elements and on my PC they are barely using any resources.

[image: Without Mouse Movement, Low Render Usage]

It's honestly impressive that it preforms that well, but if I'm moving the mouse, it's a completely different story.

[image: With Mouse Movement, High Render Usage]

The only difference is that I am constantly moving my mouse. I want to know why this happens, and if there is anything I can do to improve it. None of these elements have any mouse interaction, no JavaScript listeners, no CSS hover effects or anything like that. I am confused why moving the mouse would then have such a major effect. This high resource usage also happens even when the elements aren't visible and are scrolled past. The window is focused for all benchmarks.

The animation that I am talking about are using transforms and opacity. When using other properties like width, height, margin I get high resource usage no matter what.

Here are several things that I have tried to change this with no noticeable difference in performance.

- `pointer-events: none`, unsurprisingly no effect. I didn't think it worked like that.
- `will-change`
- `display: inline-block` vs `position: absolute` layout
- `transform` vs `opacity` animations
- `translate3d` vs `translate`
- Elements outside of the viewport (scrolled past)

I'm guessing this has to do with a GPU and as soon as the mouse moves, it requires the CPU to do something. This would explain the lack of difference on properties that require to CPU to calculate, and properties that can use the GPU are effected so dramatically.

I'm noticing this using Brave and Edge for sure. I don't under the Firefox tool enough to confidently say the same for them, although it appears to happen as well.

How can I make this always run as in the first case? I am never using any mouse interaction, so these elements could careless what it happening with the mouse from my perspective.

Here is a code snippet that should be able to produce the effect. I also have here on a GitHub pages site.

https://jack-stoller.github.io/so_demo.html

```
<style>
    body {
      padding-bottom: 150vw;
    }

    div {
      position: absolute;

      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      pointer-events: none;
      will-change: transform;
      background-color: red;
      animation: Animation 2s ease infinite;
    }

    @keyframes Animation {
      from {
        transform: scale(0);
      }

      to {
        transform: scale(1);
      }
    }
</style>
<body></body>
<script>
    const size = 50 + 8 + 8;
    const count = Math.floor(window.innerWidth / size);

    [...Array(1000)].forEach((_, i) => {
      let div = document.createElement('div');
      div.style.top = Math.floor(i / count) * size + 'px';
      div.style.left = Math.floor(i % count) * size + 'px';
      document.body.appendChild(div);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What’s your GPU usage like? I can imagine the system shovelling odd transform and opacity to a GPU but perhaps not other changes which may move other elements.

Comment: @AHaworth, I'm not for sure if there is a way to do that from the debugger, but if I look at it from Task manager, I can see my GPU usage go from 0% to 8% almost exactly any time I view the page. My CPU usage hovers at 12%, but when I move my mouse it jumps to 27%. There is no difference for the GPU when I move the mouse.

Comment: The mouse is a graphic element too, which gets XOR'd (or something like that) with the graphics buffer of the browser pane by the OS. Obviously, especially when the buffer is changing a lot (animated), this takes time. Not sure which PU, but it seems in this case the CPU. After all, Windows is nothing more than a big 'ol event dispatcher. I'm not a tech, I just like to simplify things to a level I can understand and, more importantly, can remember.

Comment: Firefox profiler sees a large increase in the *Compositor* and the *WebRender* modules because it needs to keep *VSYNC*ing. And the 'mousemove' DOMEvent handling went way up, despite the `pointer-events: none`. Probably still entering the event handler (some internal callback?) just to get ignored, which takes time nonetheless.

Comment: @RenevanderLende That would make sense, but the render process of the mouse shouldn't be included in the chrome debug tools. If I hide the cursor, there is no performance difference than showing it. It must have to do with the event the browser is receiving. I forgot where but I thought I read once that `pointer-events: none` doesn't actually optimize anything, which would make sense in this case.

Comment: As said, I'm no tech, but animations and mouse movements interfere with the message dispatching mechanism. Even moving/messing with a 'hidden' mouse causes events. Granted, I'm fishing, but each event *has* to be processed. There will be differences in handling by the various OS'es and browsers, but bottom line is, they all need to process the events and dispatch messages. I bet successively hitting a 'neutral' key on the keyboard like [Ctrl] or [Shft] has a similar effect. And paradoxically enough, the browser has to trigger an event to know it has to ignore an event. Fun little puzzle...

Comment: @RenevanderLende I agree. It has to be something like that. I just wish there was a way to separate the two. For now though, I guess I'll just have to accept the performance hit until I find a solution. Thanks for your input.